# Nginx forward proxy with # in the url

Tags: regex, nginx

So I am trying to forward a url that contains a # and am having some difficulty. I have the following in the location sections:

```
  location ~* /.%23/evl {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_pass https://foo.com;
    }

  location ~* /(?!.%23/evl) {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_pass http://bar.com;
    }
```

I would like everything with

http://example.com/#/evl/* to goto foo.com

everything else to bar.com

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `#` and anything following it (known as the *fragment* or *anchor*) is not sent to the server, so `nginx` cannot process it.

Comment: So it doesn't matter where the # is located within the URL. As soon as nginx sees the # nginx stops reading.

Are you aware of any workarounds @Richard Smith ?

Comment: `nginx` never even sees it. The `#` trick is used by client-side frameworks.